# Does truncating a keyed hash make it more secure?

Tags: php, security, cookies

I would like to set a trusted browser cookie that allows a user to bypass 2-factor authentication by email if they've successfully logged in on a given machine before. The idea would be to make it easier to log in on trusted machines for convenience.

My idea is to create a keyed hash of the email address like so:

```
<?php
define('HASH_KEY', '5sqAgsdwqNWEHpEz3pAFVQUb2Mr7acHtuezKSVykX52bCKeSJmo236HtE0U9Noj2);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $email, HASH_KEY);
// E.g. '9fa0d85b36919dc87ee01171edf6bdc302ffbc78e0c7f1738d295e76e442ccd4'
```

And then truncate it to say 16 digits:

```
$hash = substr($hash, 0, 16);
// E.g. '9fa0d85b36919dc87'
?>
```

The plan would then be to store the truncated hash in a cookie as a trusted browser token. Then, when the user attempts to log in later, the complete hash is regenerated using the same HASH_KEY and the email address supplied during login, then the first 16 digits of the new hash are compared with the cookie. If they match, 2fa is bypassed, otherwise we require it.

So my question is, does this truncation process make the hash more secure as it's incomplete? Or am I just as well using the full hash as there's no difference?

Comment: is prob fine, 16 bytes is enough entropy to make it secure if its just a flag to skip 2-factor and your still doing the login as normal, id argue with other checks in place like failed logins count you could even get away with 4 chars

Comment: BS. It is not 16 bytes of "entropy" because they are taken from a base 64 encoded string (6 bits per character). Besides that, it is much more secure to use the full 256 bit output. It's generally better to ask these things at [security.se]. 4 characters provides you 24 bits of security, which is laughably low.